# MongoDb C# Class with no ObjectID

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to have a pure class that represent a mongodb entity but with no ObjectId field.
like this:

```
 public class User 
    {
        //public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

and to be able to use my code like this:

```
db.GetCollection<User>("users").Find(Builders<User>.Filter.Empty).ToList();
```

but right now i just get an exception because i need id...
and bdw my insert function is working without the need of id:

```
public void Insert(User user)
{
     db.GetCollection<User>("users").InsertOne(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of options:

- Projection:

  ```
  // in Find
  var result = coll.FindSync(Builders<User>.Filter.Empty, new FindOptions<User>() { Projection = "{ _id : 0 }" }).ToList();
  // in Aggregate
  var result = coll.Aggregate().Project("{ _id : 0 }").ToList();
  ```
- $unset aggregation stage:

  ```
  var result = coll.Aggregate<User>(pipeline: PipelineDefinition<User,User>.Create("{ $unset : '_id' }")).ToList();
  ```
- you may look at [IgnoringExtraElements](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/bson/mapping/), but it will require changes in your class

Comment: looks better than my solution, thanks.

Comment: mark question as resolved then to reduce attention to it

Comment: how do i do it ?

Comment: Click accept answer: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

nvm guys i solved it like this :

```
public IList<User> GetCollection()
{
    var tempList = new List<User>();
    var a = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("users").Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty).ToList();
            a.ForEach(x => tempList.Add(
                new User() { FirstName = x.GetValue("FirstName").ToString(), LastName = x.GetValue("LastName").ToString() }));

    return tempList;
}
```

Comment: this is a bad approach since it will be client side transformation rather than server involving